# Specialize class template for variadic parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization

I want to specialize a class template for variadic parameters:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct TypeList
{
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
};

//Is next "specialization" even possible?
template <typename... Ts>
class Foo<TypeList<Ts...>>
{
};

Foo<TypeList<int, int>> i1{}; // OK
Foo<int, int> i2{}; // NOK:  error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
```

I want that users of `Foo` can choose between providing a `TypeList` or an explicit list of types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do, to allow both syntaxs:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class Foo : Foo<TypeList<Ts...>>
{
};

// Specialization
template <typename ... Ts>
class Foo<TypeList<Ts...>>
{
// ...
};
```

Comment: *"Specialize class template for variadic parameters"*, so in fact, it is in the other order, specialize for `TypeList`.

Comment: Great, thx! Is it also possible to provide a specialization for a default type list like so
template <>
class MsgDispatcher<MsgDispatcherTypeList>
{
}